# Add front slash to python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Currently, in a Python program, I use

```
self.regex_string = re.compile("^\w+(-\w+)*$")
```

To check an input string for alphanumeric plus hyphen characters.

I need to change the regex to allow front slashes ( / )

I'm lost in the forest of regexing.  Could someone suggest a change to my regex that will add front slash to the allowable characters?

Alternatively, is there a more efficient regex that would allow 
( A-z, a-z, 0-9, - and / ) 
with no spaces?

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly should front slashes be allowed?  Just as alternatives to hyphens?  As another kind of "word" character?

Comment: Also, are you aware that `\w` matches underscores in addition to alphanumeric characters?  Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes, I knew about the underscores, I forgot to put that in the explanation.  The front slashes can appear anywhere except the first character of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A narrow change to your regex so that in each place `\w` is allowed, `/` is also allowed:

```
^(\w|/)+(-(\w|/)+)*$
```

If you were using substitution groups, the group numbers change with this regex due to the additional parens.  In Python source you can use a raw string to avoid escaping the `\`s most of the time:

```
self.regex_string = re.compile(r'^(\w|/)+(-(\w|/)+)*$')
```

Bonus, additionally rejecting strings containing `//` as requested:

```
self.regex_string = re.compile(r'^(\w|/(?!/))+(-(\w|/(?!/))+)*$')
```

This uses a zero-width negative lookahead assertion `/(?!/)` meaning "slash not followed by another slash".

Comment: Thanks WBerry, your solution works.  One other thing I forgot to mention, it would be good if two adjacent front slashes were rejected: i.e.  this/is/a/test is ok but this//is/a/test is rejected

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a character class:

```
self.regex_string = re.compile("^\w+[\w\-/]*$")
```

Brackets (`[]`) define character classes, which will match anything inside of them. For example, `[A-Cd-fG]` would only allow A, B, C, d, e, f, and G.